# Update options to jQuery slider via form

Tags: jquery-ui, slider

I have a [jQuery Slider](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider), and I am trying to make it more dynamic by adding three input fields:

> min
>
> max
>
> step

I want to take those fields and then `onblur` update my slider options. I read that you can set options like this:

```
$('.selector').slider('option', 'max', 7);
```

And do the same for min,step, etc along with the other options.

I tried playing with it yesterday, but I'm not sure how to get it to update. I am using a form with no submit button, so just change on blur.

I know I would get the `.val()` of the input and set it to a variable then would it be:

```
 $('.selector').slider('option', 'max', var_here);
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this, assuming that your min input has an id of 'min'

```
$('#min').blur(function() {
  var newMin = parseInt($(this).val());
  $('.selector').slider('option', 'min', newMin);
});
```